# asp.net gridview jquery server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, gridview

I made an asp.net gridview using jQuery to select a row with css and I want to send this row to the server.

I've used a Query String but is there a better method to send the row to the server ?

Comment: You can invoke a serverside function through jquery.
[See this Answers][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems okay if you need to pass everything, including the markup; otherwise, you can simply take the values in the cells of the row, and put them in hidden input elements and then post the form. As long as you give names to the hidden elements, you can easily retrieve them using:

```
Request.Params["InputElementName"]
```

Comment: do you mean use hidden field then submit the from and get the value by server ?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You could POST the row to the page that needs to deal with it.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149282/post-asp-net-form-data-to-another-page).

Comment: i don't have select button just some styles