# How to pass dropdownlist value to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList with button:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDay" runat="server"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Save" runat="server" id="btn"/>
</form>
```

C# code for the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn.ServerClick+=new EventHandler(btn_ServerClick);
}

void btn_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext value= HttpContext.Current;
    value.Items.Add("Day", DropDay.SelectedValue);
    Server.Transfer("ASP_2.aspx");
}
```

In ASP_2 I have a label, that I need to set the selected Dropdownlist value. And here is the code for ASP_2.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext value= HttpContext.Current;
    lblDay.Text = value.Items["Day"].ToString();
}
```

The problem is, that the value always is the first item from the dropdown. How do I set the selected value?
**EDIT**

the way I am filling the dropdown list The code goes in Page_Load:

```
DropDay.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    DropDay.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: All looks good in that code, the problem is how you fill the drop down list and why the selectedValue is the first every time ? Maybe you fill it again on post back ?

Comment: have you tried DropDay.SelectedText ? are you sure you are assigning the right value? also try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149282/post-asp-net-form-data-to-another-page) post

Comment: At which time do you do your DropDownList binding ? If it is done on page_load and does not handle ispostback condition, your selected value will be reset before the button_click is processed. You should probably bind your list during prerender, on !PostBack

Comment: @jbl Edited the post, now showing how the list is filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for filling the DDL should be (at least) :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  DropDay.Items.Clear();
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      {
          DropDay.Items.Add(i.ToString());
      }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: thanks for the tip. :)
I have only recently started to learn ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in first page:

```
Server.Transfer("ASP_2.aspx?dropdown="+DropDay.SelectedValue);


and in the second page

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string val=Request.QueryString["dropdown"].toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you left the autopostback property of the dropdownlist true.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it by myself, just needed to remove "DropDay.Items.Clear();"

```
    //DropDay.Items.Clear(); removed this line and the thing was fixed
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    DropDay.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is not a good practice for standard asp.net webform with postback scenario. You are adding 10 more items to your list, making it a 20 items list. You don't see it because of the Server.Transfer
You should work on the postback mechanism and page lifecycle. It will help you a lot when building more complex features

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried DropDay.SelectedItem.Text?