# How do I receive form data which was posted in another page in the same website

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post, webforms

Let's say I have one html web-page (*form.html*) containing a simple form which is sent using POST method:

```html
<body>
   <form name="Form1" method="POST" action="process.aspx">
      <input name="firstname" type="text" value="" />
      <input name="lastname" type="text" value="" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
   </form>
</body>
```

Now, in another page at the same directory (process.aspx) I want to process the data in some way. How do I fetch this data? What I tried to do is:

```
string firstname = Request.Form["firstname"];
string lastname = Request.Form["lastname"];
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149282/post-asp-net-form-data-to-another-page)

Comment: Where are you trying to fetch the data? I recreated your scenario and I was able to retrieve the data just fine in Process.aspx in the `Page_Load()` handler.

Comment: ledbutter is right: your approach is correct (I tried it myself too). Are you having any errors? What exactly is your problem?